# Git: Moving my own commits to top of the branch and resetting

Tags: git

I'm fairly new when it comes to more complex Git commands, so I need a little help with this one. So things are currently like this:

```
origin/master
1->2->3->4

master
1->A->2->3->4
   |
 my commit
```

At the moment, I have committed A.  I'm not completely satisfied how it turned out, but I haven't pushed it to origin/master yet. I also have some local changes that I would like to include to A in addition to changing some stuff in A. From what I've read, I can move my local commit A ahead of 4, which would look like this

```
master
1->2->3->4->A
```

I would then like to soft reset to commit 4 so that I would have the changes from commit A and current local changes as uncommitted changes. So the commands I've found out would be the following:

```
git stash
git rebase ???
git reset --soft 4
git stash pop
```

So as end result, I'd like to have the changes from commit A and previous local changes now together as local changes. Is what I described possible with the commands above? How would I move my local commit A to the top with rebase? Assuming everything works now, can I safely pop my stash together with the reset commit A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After stashing, you should rebase interactively:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~4 # Rebase up to the last 4 most recent commits.
```

Then in the editor popping up, reorder commits as you wish and make `A` the *bottom-most* (in contrast to `gitk`, this view shows the most recent commit at the bottom, not at the top). Exit the editor, saving the file, and let Git do the rebasing. Resolve any conflicts if necessary. Then reset and pop the stash like you did in your example.

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I needed. Everything went exactly as I described.

Answer (score 0):

If you've run `git fetch` and there are changes, and you've not pushed your local changes yet:-

`git pull --rebase` will do what you want - it rewinds the HEAD to the point before you started, pulls in the latest changes from upstream, and then replays your changes so that they appear in sequence.

Any conflicts are resolved at the point where they would have appeared, rather than in a merge commit.